# selenium fail to find element by tag name

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to do some data scraping from a website and I need to get a certain element at some point. The element's name and id are dynamically generated to the XPATH, CSS_SELECTOR, ID are unusable. I'm trying to use the tag name to get the element but it fails. I'm getting the parent element (li in this case) and applying the find_element() function to get the very first child element () but it doesn't work. The reason I have to get this specific element is that there is a shadow root stemming from it that I need to expand.

Python code:

```
    nb_cv=0
    liens_profils=[]
    nb_cv_dmd=int(nb_cv_dmd)
    while nb_cv<nb_cv_dmd:

      #on ouvre le premier shadow root

        WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="resultslist"]')))
        liste_profils_shadow= expand_shadow_element(driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='//*[@id="resultslist"]'))
        #on recupere l'élément parent des profils et on récupère tous les profils
        parent_profils=liste_profils_shadow.find_element(by=By.ID,value="list")
 profils=parent_profils.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME,value="li")
        for profil in profils:
            if nb_cv<nb_cv_dmd:
                try:
                    #WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME,"results-card")))
                    result_card=profil.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME,value="results-card")
                    result_card_shadow=expand_shadow_element(result_card)
```

[The element i'm trying to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsNpx.png)

HTML:

```
 <!-- Liste de résultats -->
        <results-list class="resultslist"
                      id="resultslist"
                      state=[{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:17595816,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:14747406,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:17816114,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:15634996,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:17641294,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:17808000,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:16696140,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:13730612,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:16623996,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:17435668,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:17809379,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:15037379,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:17781323,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:10005222,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:17805944,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:17415932,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:13931906,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:15098652,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:17745872,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}},{&quot;idCandidat&quot;:17790259,&quot;isSelected&quot;:false,&quot;iscollapsed&quot;:true,&quot;hello&quot;:{&quot;helloState&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;helloNeedFeedback&quot;:false}}] withPreview>
                    <template slot="17595816" data-results-card>
                        


<results-card id="person_17595816"
              data-candidat-id="17595816"
              data-over-url="/Recherche/CvOver?candidateId=17595816&amp;guid=4739f03b-bc68-47e5-ba5c-9a79f1978d44&amp;Position=1&amp;NbResultats=966&amp;isAnonymized=False&amp;IdSource=1&amp;OngletProjet=Candidats&amp;OngletSelectionne=ParDate&Sources=1"
              
              
              
              
              
              
              
              
              
              
              
              
              mobility='{
        "otherDeps":[&quot;95&quot;,&quot;78&quot;,&quot;91&quot;,&quot;94&quot;,&quot;77&quot;,&quot;92&quot;,&quot;75&quot;,&quot;93&quot;],
        "homeDep":"76",
        "isForeign":false,
        "location":"Saint-&#201;tienne-du-Rouvray",
        "mobility":[]
    }'
              infos='{
        "qualification":"3",
        "exp":"1",
        "posteRecherche":&quot;D&#233;veloppeur web, \u003cspan class=\&quot;highlight\&quot;\u003eDevOps\u003c/span\u003e, D&#233;veloppeur Java JEE&quot;,
        "sector":[&quot;Informatique / T&#233;l&#233;com / Multim&#233;dia&quot;],
        "salary":"&#192; convenir",
        "handicap":false,
        "dispo":"Imm&#233;diate"
    }'
              data='{
        "posteActuel":&quot;Ing&#233;nieur d\u0027&#233;tudes et d&#233;veloppement informatique&quot;,
        "name":&quot;Ulrich KENMOGNE KAMGUIA&quot;,
        "linkUrl": "/Profil?CandidateId=17595816&amp;Position=1&amp;NbResultats=966&amp;NbParPages=11&amp;IdSource=1&amp;Sources=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSystem.Int32%5D&amp;GuidRecherche=4739f03b-bc68-47e5-ba5c-9a79f1978d44&amp;OngletSelectionne=ParDate&amp;CvCurrentPage=1&amp;NbPageCv=0&amp;OngletProjet=Candidats&amp;FromSelection=False&amp;FromNotification=False&amp;StartFrom=0&amp;IndexCandidatListe=0&amp;CurrentPosition=0&amp;IdRecherche=0&amp;SourceOriginePage=Recherche&amp;sources=1",
        "sitePicto":"BDM/job",
        "sitePictoLabel":"BDM/job",
        "date":"21/06/2022 13:08:05",
        "isMoreThan12Month":false,
        "idCandidat":"17595816"
    }'
              buttonsData='{
        "idCandidat":"17595816",
        "idProjet":"",
        "name":&quot;Ulrich KENMOGNE KAMGUIA&quot;,
        "idSource":"1",
        "currentPosition":"1",
        "currentCandidate":"17595816",
        "sources":"1",
        "extensionOriginale":"",
        "hash":"b625f3af37973803d90b964f04da93d3"
    }'
              tags='[]'>
```

exception:

```
Message: invalid argument: invalid locator
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.115)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x0113D953+2414931]
        Ordinal0 [0x010CF5E1+1963489]
        Ordinal0 [0x00FBC6B8+837304]
        Ordinal0 [0x00FE9691+1021585]
        Ordinal0 [0x00FE97EB+1021931]
        Ordinal0 [0x00FDFD21+982305]
        Ordinal0 [0x010044E4+1131748]
        Ordinal0 [0x00FDFC74+982132]
        Ordinal0 [0x010046B4+1132212]
        Ordinal0 [0x01014812+1198098]
        Ordinal0 [0x010042B6+1131190]
        Ordinal0 [0x00FDE860+976992]
        Ordinal0 [0x00FDF756+980822]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013ACC62+2510274]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0139F760+2455744]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x011CEABA+551962]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x011CD916+547446]
        Ordinal0 [0x010D5F3B+1990459]
        Ordinal0 [0x010DA898+2009240]
        Ordinal0 [0x010DA985+2009477]
        Ordinal0 [0x010E3AD1+2046673]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76C9FA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x777A7A7E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x777A7A4E+238]
```

I don't really know why but the HTML seems different when I inspect the page's source code than when I inspect it with developer tools.

Comment: Could you kindly post exceptions (if any) and the whole html (could be that your code catches tags prior to the one you look for)? And `parent_profils` as well.

Comment: I have added the exception and the full html as well as more of my python code